# ReactJS: how to trigger form submit event from another event

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I've two react events:

1. Form submit event

   ```
   sendMessage: function(event){
       console.log(event);
       event.preventDefault();
   },
   ```
2. keyPress Event

   ```
   textareaKeypress: function(event){
       if (event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey){
           document.getElementById('messagebox').submit();
       }
   },
   ```

but the reactJS is not capturing the form submit triggered by `textareaKeypress`. How can I call the `sendMessage` from `textareaKeypress` with proper event?

Comment: My question is not about why this code isn't working, the question is about how to implement form submit trigger which can be catched by reactjs events.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. I'm only talking about the formatting of your question, not your code/problem. You used "stack snippets" in your question, which allow us to directly run code on Stack Overflow, by adding big "run code snippet" buttons (see http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28904875/1). But if your code examples are not excutable on their own, there is no need to use them. It will just clutter your question with those buttons.

Comment: i.e. Try using a Code Sample (curly braces in message editor) instead of Code Snippets (page with brackets icon).

Comment: @FelixKling ohh, sorry, totally misunderstood that.
 SeanO Thanks. I'll keep remember that from next time

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I learned something new today: this is just how the DOM works.

From [the MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit):

> The form's onsubmit event handler (for example, `onsubmit="return false;"`) will not be triggered when invoking this method from Gecko-based applications. In general, it is not guaranteed to be invoked by HTML user agents.

According to [the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#htmlformelement):

> The `submit()` method, when invoked, must submit the `form` element from the `form` element itself, **with the submitted from `submit()` method flag set**.

followed by (section 4.10.22.3)

> **If the submitted from `submit()` method flag is not set, then fire a simple event** that bubbles and is cancelable named `submit`, at *form*.

So, the event is not fired if the `submit()` method flag is set.

---

I was able to get the behavior you (and I) were expecting via the following code ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/c2Let3te/)):

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="form">
  <textarea onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
</form>

// ...

this.refs.form.getDOMNode().dispatchEvent(new Event("submit"));
```

(You'll need [more verbose code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) in IE.)

jQuery's `$(form).submit()` [delegates to](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/222ac3ad6bd40ef4dfb4e4c60bac4b751d907e2a/src/event/alias.js#L6-17) `$(form).trigger("submit")`, so I expect it's a similar workaround.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for your answer. Had a hard time finding it (was trying to do something similar with auto-submitting a form when a checkbox was clicked), but this solved my problem.

Comment: Use `this.refs.form.submit();` instead of `this.refs.form.getDOMNode().dispatchEvent(new Event("submit"));`

Comment: @frevib As stated in both the question and this answer, `submit()` doesn't trigger **React**'s `submit` event, thus the workaround

Comment: If above does not work for anyone then try this - ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.form).dispatchEvent(new Event("submit")); And import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

Answer (score 11):

### New method (24.08.2022)

Form element now has a [`requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) method, which would trigger submit event by itself without workarounds, as stated in [`submit()` MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit):

> The `HTMLFormElement.submit()` method submits a given [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).
>
> This method is similar, but not identical to, activating a form's
> submit [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). When invoking this method directly, however:
>
> - No [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) event is raised. In particular, the form's `onsubmit` event handler is not run.
> - [Constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation) is not triggered.
>
> The [`HTMLFormElement.requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) method is identical to activating a form's submit [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) and does not have these differences.

However, this method is [not supported well enough](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlformelement_requestsubmit) on IE and Safari 15.6. As of 02.09.2022, this is about 76.49% global usage. If you need a more browser-compatible solution, keep reading until the end.

### No need to use `ref`s

Every answer I've yet seen uses refs when you actually don't need them. Most (if not all) of the form controls have a reference to a parent form in their `form` property:

```js
textarea.form.requestSubmit();
```

Just make sure to attach a handler on one of the form controls, for example: [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement), [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement), [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement), [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).

With all that said, you can write your handlers like that:

```html
<form onSubmit={this.sendMessage}>
    <textarea onKeyPress={this.textareaKeypress}/>
</form>
```

```js
sendMessage: function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
},

textareaKeypress: function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
        event.target.form.requestSubmit();
    }
},
```

Or if you care about browser compatibility, dispatch an event manually (thanks to [Karol Dabrowski answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65667238/12320578)):

```js
textareaKeypress: function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
        event.target.form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', { cancelable: true, bubbles: true }));
    }
},
```

Comment: this is ace, thanks @Vasiliy Artamonov, for anyone wanting to add types to this, see my answer which extends upon this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74558120/827129

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [@VasiliyArtamonov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73471976/827129), here's how I got it working with Typescript:

```js
const onKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>): void => {
  const commandKeyPressed = e.metaKey;
  const enterKeyPressed = e.key === "Enter";
  if (commandKeyPressed && enterKeyPressed) e.currentTarget.form?.requestSubmit();
};
```

*Updated to include the tweak in @VasiliyArtamonov's comment below*.

Comment: For avoiding issues with TypeScript, you have to use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). That way you can get rid of type assertion (`as ...`). The element inside `currentTarget` is where the handler is **attached**; the element inside `target` is the one that **triggered** the event, which is not always the same as `currentTarget`. [Comparison of Event Targets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets).

Comment: Thanks @VasiliyArtamonov, I've gone ahead and updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

It's your component, so you don't need to worry about passing actual events around.  You have some event handlers, and then you have the actual action.

```
sendMessage: function(){
    console.log('message:', this.state.message);
},
handleFormSubmit: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.sendMessage();
},
handleTextareaKeypress: function(event){
    if (event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey){
        this.sendMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the wrong answer. Cause I'm working with some thirdparty module and there are exist inner onSubmit handler. If I trigger form.submit() manually this handler won't be triggered.