# Form submission in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to submit a form in React. This form is `connected one` so the form data will be coming as props. What I'm trying to achieve is the form should be autosubmitted when `props are different` that means a form should be autosubmitted only once for a single set of props.

I tried adding a condition in `componentWillReceiveProps` also where I can determine if the props are different, submit form. Initially, `this.props` is undefined in first render of `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { formSubmitted: false }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.picmonicVideoData.data.signature !== nextProps.picmonicVideoData.data.signature) {
      this.setState({formSubmitted: false});
  }
  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    if (!this.state.formSubmitted) {
      this.setState({ formSubmitted: true })
      document.getElementById('ltiLaunchForm').submit()
    }
  } 
  render() {
    let renderInputFields = null
    if (this.props.videoData.data.hasOwnProperty("signature")) {
      renderInputFields = Object.keys(launchData).map((key, i) => {
        return (<input type="hidden" name={key} key={i} value={launchData[key]} />)
      })
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <iframe width="100%" height="430px" frameBorder="0" name="videoIframe"></iframe>
        <form name="ltiLaunchForm" id="ltiLaunchForm" method="post" target="target_iframe" encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action={launchUrl}>
          {renderInputFields}
          <input type="hidden" name="oauth_signature" value={signature} />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whats the error/problem?

Comment: same form is being submitted.

Comment: so you submit(), change form values, submit() again but it submits the old form values? also you can remove`componentDidUpdate(...)` completely and replace `this.setState({formSubmitted: false});` with `document.getElementById('ltiLaunchForm').submit();`

Comment: Personally I would use refs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901223/react-js-submit-form-programmatically-does-not-trigger-onsubmit-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise here to use `componentDidUpdate` only as you can easily compare the `prevProps` and current `props` and perform your submit action.  So your code would look something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => {
    if (this.props !== prevProps) {
      document.getElementById('ltiLaunchForm').submit()
    }
  }
```

You will no longer need `componentWillReceiveProps` and also avoid using the deprecated lifecycles from React if you are planning to use React 16.3 and above. For detailed explanation, have a look at this [link](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html).

Comment: thanks @Pranay, what would be the right place for generating dynamic id's. I'm using `uuid` package for it. If i write `let picmonicUUID = uuid()` inside constructor I will get same Id for updated props form as well. Any suggestion?

Comment: I would say generate it in parent component and then pass it down to the child.