# How to trigger reactjs form submit from button eventhandler to fixed URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to trigger a reactjs form submission **from a button eventhandler** to a **fixed URL**.

So far, I have seen *SO* examples (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904875/reactjs-how-to-trigger-form-submit-event-from-another-event)) of form submission  with a button of type `submit`

and with buttons of type `button` and `onClick` eventhandler, which seems to need a form with `onSubmit` eventhandler (see examples below)

`With submit button inside form` *Working!*

```
  render(){
  return(
     <div>
         <form id="form1" method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/">
             <label>
                 Name:
                 <input type="text" name="name" enctype='text/plain' value={this.state.data}  />
                 <button type="submit">Submit inside form</button>
             </label>
         </form>
```

`With submit button and eventhandler` *Also working!*

```
         <form id="form3" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <label>
             Name:
             <input type="text" name="name" enctype='text/plain' value={this.state.data}  />
             <button type="submit">submit</button>
         </label>
        </form>
        <button
         onClick={ () =>
             document.getElementById('form3').dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'))}
        >
         This works
        </button>
```

I would just need to trigger a simple submit with an `action` from a `button with an eventhandler`, like in the not-working example below.

```
<form id="form4" method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/"  
onSubmit={this.doNothingLetActionDoTheJob}>
             <label>
                 Name:
                 <input type="text" name="name" enctype='text/plain' value={this.state.data}  />
                 <button type="submit">submit</button>
             </label>
         </form>
         <button
             onClick={ () =>
                 document.getElementById('form4').dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'))}
         >
             This does not work
         </button>
```

Is this possible? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to do that way?

Comment: Because I don't want to write code for posting data.
Which means to *require* packages and struggle with package version issues and all sorts of that stuff.

Comment: You can use fetch and perform a AJAX call which would not require any additional libraries.

Comment: @Ganeshchaitanya Do you by chance know, the best way to set the *HTML* response of the POST in the current window - which means: injecting the response into my active document. I am aware of security concerns!

Comment: this.state = {
 data = "";
}

componentDidMount(){
 fetch('some_url')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
}

<div> {this.state.data} </div>

Try this