# How to submit form on change of input value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a form which has an `onSubmit` I want to run this function every time the user changes a value in the input field so I have attached this little function on the form

```
       onChange={() => {
         formRef.current?.submit();
       }}
```

My problem is that now when I change values in the input the page refreshes even trought I have `e.preventDefault();` on my `onSubmit`

```
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS: how to trigger form submit event from another event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904875/reactjs-how-to-trigger-form-submit-event-from-another-event)

Comment: I have tried formRef.current?.dispatchEvent(new Event("submit")) but it doesn't do anything when I console.log it I receive a value of true but again nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem as well. I've added specific typing for the event parameter, which resolved my problems so far. I don't understand why you want to perform a `onSubmit` on every change. Personally, I would run the `onSubmit` if the element loses focus, but to answer your question:

Replace your `onSubmit` function with this:

```js
onSubmit=((e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // ...
})
```

Comment: I had added a specific types but it hasn't solved my problem

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? Or what does not go as expected? Does it still redirect to another page?

Comment: Yes, nothing had changed in behavior of both, formRef.current?.submit(); and formRef.current?.dispatchEvent(new Event("submit"))
I had found a work around but am still interested in the solution for my problem if there is one.

Comment: Did you console.log() the formRef.current?